# A vector of list type

Tags: c++, vector, linked-list

I am trying to declare a vector of List type. I've searched around and from what I can find and gather, I believe that this declaration `vector <List<int>> adj` is correct. But VS is giving me an error that "List" may not have a template argument list.

**Graph.H**

```
#ifndef GRAPH_H_
#define GRAPH_H_

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include "List.h"

class Graph {

public:
    Graph(int n);
    //Initializes an empty graph to have n vertices

    ~Graph();

    int getNumEdges();

    int getNumVertices();

    void addEdge(int u, int v);

    void printGraph();

private:

    int vertices, edges;

    vector<List<int>> adj; <---The Issue I am having
};
#endif
```

**List.h**

```
class List
{
private:
    struct Node
    {
        int data;
        Node* next;

        Node() : next(NULL){} //define our own default constructor
        Node(int data) : next(NULL), data(data){}
    };

    typedef struct Node* NodeRef;

    NodeRef head;
    NodeRef tail;
    NodeRef iterator; //points to one node at a time
    int size;
```

Comment: `List` is not a template, so why would you try to parametrize it using `<int>`?

Comment: Just `vector<List>`.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant  so when I try that, now I get missing type specifier - int assumed C++ does not support default int

Comment: @AlanStokes now i get missing type specifier - int assummed. C++ does not support default-int

Comment: @Bryan There's no "default-int". `List` has **no type parameters,** since it is **not a template.** If you are trying to use `std::list`, which I suspect might be the case, that's an entirely different story, because `std::list` **is** a template, so you **have** to supply the type parameter.

Comment: @Bryan That's a new question. No way to answer it without seeing exactly what you did.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that your intent is to implement an adjacency matrix of type int. In this case, you should not use that `List`, but `std::list`. If that's what you want, these are the required changes:

```
#include <list>
...
std::vector<std::list<int>> adj;
```

Answer (score 0):

> But VS is giving me an error that "List" may not have a template
>   argument list.

Some error messages in C++ may be hard to decipher, but where's the problem with this one? `List` is not a template. It may not have a template argument list:

> ```
> class List
> {
> // ...
> };
> ```

You may make `List` a template, of course:

```
template <class T>
class List
{
private:
    struct Node
    {
        T data;
        Node* next;

        Node() : next(NULL){} //define our own default constructor
        Node(T const& data) : next(NULL), data(data){}
    };

    typedef struct Node* NodeRef;

    NodeRef head;
    NodeRef tail;
    NodeRef iterator; //points to one node at a time
    int size;
};
```

But why would you do that? Just use `std::list` and be done with it.

In other words, in C++ the most natural way to express "a vector of list type" is `std::vector<std::list<int>>`.

Comment: now I get missing type specifier - int assumed C++ does not support default in